# Strange graphics artifacts (like diagnostics circle) in games and Viber

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, display-driver, visual-artifacts

I have strange graphics artifacts in Viber and 3D applications (like some games). This is stange circle maybe some kind of diagnostics one but I don't know what is it.

Maybe you know how to solve it?

I have attached screenshot from Viber. My hardware spects: AMD Pheonm X4 970, ASUS M5A97 R2.0 motherboard, 16 GB RAM and  my videocard is GeForce GTX 770, Windows 7 64bit (SP1) and Nvidia driver 364.72)

Viber screenshot with strange artifact like circle:

[image]

Comment: you probably have installed something that injects an overlay into 3d applications. Steam does this by default, fraps does this, so anything you may have installed, even things that "fix" older 3d games for use on newer hardware and widescreen does this.

Comment: Ok, I will try to search for something like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for advise. It was ASUS Xonar Audio Center :))) I have turned off it and removed from autoload and circle was gone. I use ASUS Xonar  DX audio card. This is strange but it seems that asus do "great" software for their audio cards :)))

Comment: I will do this after system allows me to do this. For now I am not allowed. I need to wait 16 hours.